# How to check if table exists?

Tags: python, sql

I'm using this function :

```
def checker(name,s)
        MY_T = "SELECT count(*) FROM `"+session.SessionInfo.Name where EventName='"+name+"'"
```

I want to check if the table exists, how can I do it?

I saw some examples using `XXXX.execute()`. What does it mean?

Here is what I saw:

```
query = cursor.execute("""SELECT count(*) FROM scan WHERE prefix = %s and code_id = %s and answer = %s and station_id = %s""",
                          (prefix, code_id, answer, station,))
        if query != 1:
```

I tried printing MY_T to see if it returns -1 for example but it just prints `"select count (*)...... "`

How can I check it?

Comment: `query = cursor.execute("""SELECT count(*) FROM scan WHERE prefix = %s and code_id = %s and answer = %s and station_id = %s""", (prefix, code_id, answer, station,))`
This is very unsafe, you should use binded variables instead.

Comment: I'm afraid this depends on the databases you're using. With sqlite3, you can do `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'the_table_name'`

Comment: Which database / driver are you using? can you provide more info?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the "TABLES" information schema view.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'YOUR TABLE'
```

You can apply this view to your code by doing something like the following:

```
def checkTableExists(dbcon, tablename):
    dbcur = dbcon.cursor()
    dbcur.execute("""
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_name = '{0}'
        """.format(tablename.replace('\'', '\'\'')))
    if dbcur.fetchone()[0] == 1:
        dbcur.close()
        return True

    dbcur.close()
    return False
```

Comment: not sure I understood (my first time with python and sql). when I'm using : MY_T=... - > I'm creating the table and saving it under the MY_T parameter right? so where should your code go? what is the information schema? and what if there is no table_name?(meaning it wasn't created) - what should it return?

Comment: I recommend letting the cursor.execute() function do substitutions rather than doing it yourself with str.format()

Comment: postgres also has information_schema.tables, this solution works for postgres.

Comment: MSSQL also has information_schema.tables, this solution works for MSSQL

Comment: SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name' AND table_name = 'table_name';

Comment: `information_schema.tables` includes information from all databases. If you have multiple databases, you have to use `WHERE table_schema = 'database name' AND table_name = 'table name'`

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Python-MySQL (MySQLdb) -> http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

cursor.execute() is the method to run queries with MySQLdb, Python MySQL driver. You can pass two arguments, like:

```
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

And will execute "statement" parsing "parameters" to the statement. You need to have opened a database connection and also open a cursor

I think you can use MySQL's statement: **SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tablename';**

```
stmt = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tableName'"
cursor.execute(stmt)
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result:
    # there is a table named "tableName"
else:
    # there are no tables named "tableName"
```

EDIT: there will other Python drivers with similar behaviour. Look for yours :)

Answer (score 2):

I found that this works well with Python 3.6 and MySql 5.7:

```
table = 'myTable'
_SQL = """SHOW TABLES"""
cursor.execute(_SQL)
results = cursor.fetchall()

print('All existing tables:', results) # Returned as a list of tuples

results_list = [item[0] for item in results] # Conversion to list of str

if table in results_list:
    print(table, 'was found!')
else:
    print(table, 'was NOT found!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Above answer might not work for Oracle, I found code snippet below work for Oracle:

```
import cx_Oracle
def checkTableExists(dbcon, tablename):
    dbcur = dbcon.cursor()
    try:
        dbcur.execute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(tablename))
        return True
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        x = e.args[0]
        if x.code == 942: ## Only catch ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error
            return False
        else:
            raise e
    finally:
        dbcur.close()
```

Comment: As with all solutions that create SQL statements via concatenation or formatting, the table names should be whitelisted otherwise the solution has SQL Injection security issues.

Answer (score 1):

try this code
it shows all tables. then, compare the saved tables name to your target table

change cursor to yours in your code ^_^

```
def tableExistance(table_name):

    cursor.execute('SHOW tables;')

    myresult = cursor.fetchall()

    for loacal_table_name in myresult:

        print('table name', loacal_table_name[0])
    
        if loacal_table_name[0] == table_name:
        
            return True
    
    return False

exist = tableExistance("you table name")
print('tableExistance', exist)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward way is using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) = 1 as exists FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = 'my_table';
```

that returns if table exists:

```
 exists 
--------
 t
(1 row)
```

or in Python using `psycopg2`:

```
cur.execute(
    """
    SELECT COUNT(*) = 1 FROM pg_tables WHERE tablename = 'my_table';
    """
)
exists = cur.fetchone()[0]
print(exists)
True
if exists is False:
   # table does not exist
   ...
```