# How to use python statement to check the sql table is exist or not.?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, mysql-python

I would like to know how to write the python statement to check whether the sql table is exist or not.

if the table is exist , then I will insert data to the table, otherwise, I will create the table.

The table name is "resulttable",

```
 db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","123","test")
 cursor = db.cursor()

 sql="""CREATE TABLE resulttable ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  writerName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, matchWords LONGTEXT, matchMagazine LONGTEXT, matchNews LONGTEXT )"""
 cursor.execute(sql)
 db.close()
```

how to do the checking part??

I add this statement, but I got an error:

```
   sql="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resulttable ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  writerName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, matchWords LONGTEXT, matchMagazine LONGTEXT, matchNews LONGTEXT )"""
     cursor.execute(sql)
     db.close()
```

the error is:
Warning: Table 'resulttable' already exists
  cursor.execute(sql)

Comment: why not add `IF NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: @LFJ, i got an error . _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1113, 'A table must have at least 1 column')

Comment: you did not define the column, use it like `sql="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resulttable ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, ......"""`

Comment: I followed your python statement by adding the column definition, the error is :Warning: Table 'resulttable' already exists
  cursor.execute(sql)

Comment: yes, if the table exists, it gives a warning to stdout, nothing else is done. .  if you really want to check the table, see link in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "TABLES" information schema view. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'YOUR TABLE'
```

You can apply this view to your code by doing something like the following:

```
def checkTableExists(dbcon, tablename):
    dbcur = dbcon.cursor()
    dbcur.execute("""
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_name = '{0}'
        """.format(tablename.replace('\'', '\'\'')))
    if dbcur.fetchone()[0] == 1:
        dbcur.close()
        return True

    dbcur.close()
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","123","test")
 cursor = db.cursor()

 sql="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resulttable ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  writerName CHAR(20) NOT NULL, matchWords LONGTEXT, matchMagazine LONGTEXT, matchNews LONGTEXT )"""
 cursor.execute(sql)
 # add insert staff
 # insert_sql = "inset ..."
 # cursor.execute(sql)
 cursor.close()
 db.close()
```

if you want check table if exists anyway, check this [python - how to check if table exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044259/python-how-to-check-if-table-exists)