# Is there any way to check if a table/database in mysql (python connector) exists already?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, if-statement

So, I wanted to create a program where it will take input from user about everything i.e. database name, table name, table structure(column names), data and then perform various add, delete, update etc. function on it. But I am unable to check whether the user inputted table/database already exists. I tried following code:

```
def create_table():
    table_in_database=input('Enter name of database where you want to create this table in:')
    x=mysql.connect(host=host_name,user=user_name,password=user_password,database=table_in_database)
    y=x.cursor()
    if table_in_database in y.fetchall():
        name_table=input('Enter the name of the table you want to create:')
        if name_table in y.fetchall():
            print('Table already exits, Try another or use existing table')
        else:
            table_structure=tuple(input('Enter the structure/row names of the table(seperated by commas):'))
            y.execute('create table '+name_table+''+table_structure+'')
            print('Table', name_table, 'created successfully')
            x.commit()
    else:
        print('Database', table_in_database, 'does not exist')
```

but it can't y.fetchall(), so I even tried using a different function show_database() which shows all database in place of y.fetchall() but then there is NoneType error. Is there any way by which I can check if a table/database exists or not?

Comment: Query information_schema.tables see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html And check related lower down and to the right of this page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - how to check if table exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044259/python-how-to-check-if-table-exists)

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to a database run the query `SHOW TABLES;` it will return a list of all tables in that database.
You can refine the search with conditions:

```
SHOW tables 
WHERE Tables_in_test ='triangle';
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| triangle       |
+----------------+
```

You will need to modify the name of the column to match your database.

```
Tables_in_[database_name]
```